Read string from modbus tcp via php but just showing the first character
Have followed the instruction of aldas library to read the string from Modbus TCP using FC3 but just showing the first char. I have changed the length but there is no change. Can anyone provide a syntax correction to read string, please.


Please don't post images of code. How is the string encoded? (the Modbus protocol does not provide any guidance on this so different devices do it in different ways - perhaps try reading the registers as int16 and show us the values).
